# Multiple sets of references in Bibiliography

Tags: beamer, ref

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor={table}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % <- really?
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[framesassubsections]{beamerprosper}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\beamertemplatetransparentcovereddynamic

\title[Something]
{\large Something else}


\author[Praphulla]{{\bf{Praphulla Koushik}}  \and \\
\vskip 0.5cm
\small{\inst{}\\ School}\\
}
\institute[University]{ \small{  }
}
\date{1st August 2019}

\colorlet{redshaded}{red!25!bg}
\colorlet{shaded}{black!25!bg}
\colorlet{shadedshaded}{black!10!bg}
\colorlet{blackshaded}{black!40!bg}

\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black} \colorlet{darkblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}

\def\radius{0.96cm}
\def\innerradius{0.85cm}

\def\softness{0.4}
\definecolor{softred}{rgb}{1,\softness,\softness}
\definecolor{softgreen}{rgb}{\softness,1,\softness}
\definecolor{softblue}{rgb}{\softness,\softness,1}

\definecolor{softrg}{rgb}{1,1,\softness}
\definecolor{softrb}{rgb}{1,\softness,1}
\definecolor{softgb}{rgb}{\softness,1,1}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{rosa}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,1.0}




\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{
\frametitle{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Leinster} Tom Leinster.,  \href{https://www.amazon.com/Category-Cambridge-Studies-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/1107044243}{Basic Category theory}.
\bibitem{Simmons} Harold Simmons., \href{https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Category-Theory-Harold-Simmons/dp/0521283043}{An Introduction to Category Theory}.
\end{thebibliography}
}
```

This is the minimal working example for my question. Say, I have given 10 references.

Question : Is there a way to split the references as two sets of 5 each. First five (if possible with a name, say, XXX) and second five (as YYY)?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, are you saying you want two `\subsubsection`-like headings (or similar) inside the bibliography?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. This is what I mean,,